# USART receiver on STM32

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, usart

Hi I am currently working on USART communication trying to transmit and receive data from any GPIO pin.

I am succeed to transmit data at any baud-rate when it comes to receiving i got stuck at a point.

I was able to receive a character at a time. Pin is set as external falling edge interrupt used a RX pin.

But when i transmit a string like "test" from terminal to controller only "t" is received rest 3 character is garbage value. I was thinking that after receiving first character and saving it, the Interrupt is not triggered as fast for next character.

Many things are hard coded in this sample code for test purpose.

Here the sample code for receiver

```
void EXTI0_IRQHandler(void){
r0 = GPIOA->IDR;
delay_us(delay_time);
r1 = GPIOA->IDR;
delay_us(delay_time);
r2 = GPIOA->IDR;
delay_us(delay_time);
r3 = GPIOA->IDR;
delay_us(delay_time);
r4 = GPIOA->IDR;
delay_us(delay_time);
r5 = GPIOA->IDR;
delay_us(delay_time);
r6 = GPIOA->IDR;
delay_us(delay_time);
r7 = GPIOA->IDR;
delay_us(delay_time);
r8 = GPIOA->IDR;
delay_us(delay_time);
r9 = GPIOA->IDR;
delay_us(delay_time);
r1 = r1 & 0x00000001;
r2 = r2 & 0x00000001;
r3 = r3 & 0x00000001;
r4 = r4 & 0x00000001;
r5 = r5 & 0x00000001;
r6 = r6 & 0x00000001;
r7 = r7 & 0x00000001;
r8 = r8 & 0x00000001;
x |= r8;
x = x << 1;
x |= r7;
x = x << 1;
x |= r6;
x = x << 1;
x |= r5;
x = x << 1;
x |= r4;
x = x << 1;
x |= r3;
x = x << 1;
x |= r2;
x = x << 1;
x |= r1;
buff1[z++] = x;
EXTI->PR |= 0X00000001;
x=0;
return ;}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Number of stop bits, data bits is wrong?

Comment: Sorry i forget to mention some points. I had applied logic for 1 start bit , 8 data bit and 1 stop bit.

Comment: It's bad practise to have long delays (or any delays) in interrupt handlers, they should be as short as possible. Is there any reason you're bit banging rather than using one of the many USARTs available in the STM32?

Comment: Those delay are calibrated for baudrate for example for 9600 baudrate, delay time is calibrated as 1\9600 = 104 us. There is no particular reason for this i was trying it for research purpose only.

Comment: This codes defeats the whole purpose of having an ISR in the first place. Use the UART's own interrupt or use DMA. These delays are nonsense. Bit-banging UART is nonsense; every single MCU released during the past 40 years has got UART peripheral hardware.

Comment: The _hardware_ serial transceivers on STM32 are (mostly) USARTS (i..e they support synchronous and asynchronous timing), but what you are implementing here is a _UART_ only.

Comment: @Lundin - but not every micro the ability to assign a UART Rx to an arbitrary pin;  usually only a subset of pins or a specific pin, and the board design if pre-existing may not have exposed all or any UART pins in any case - so not complete nonsense - just a last resort solution to possible hardware limitations.  The solution outlined in my answer was for an existing design with a single serial port, with a need for asymmetric  baud rates.  Helpfully on STM32 you can independently enable the USART Tx and Rx, so the hardware Tx was used for the high speed output and the soft-UART for the Rx.

Comment: Note that waiting for the STOP bit serves no purpose - its purpose is largely only to ensure that the subsequent start bit is a transition to which the bit sampling can be synchronised.  A delay following the STOP bit is certainly unnecessary and will cause you to miss the start of the second character.  That said, even without that it is a terrible solution to put delays in an interrupt handler - while data is streaming you will spend near 100% CPU time in the interrupt context getting nothing done (except higher priority interrupts).

Comment: @Lundin i am not doing it for creating any uart for any controller, i did this for better understanding of UART. Further i am fully aware of UART Interrupts and DMA, i just strike in my mind that how this thing works, so i tried to implement it in my own ways.

Comment: @Clifford thanks for your reply. It is really helpful and i will try to implement it. Might, not waiting for stop bit will help me out. I will try this.

Comment: @Vaibhav - See the addition to my answer on the STOP bit, not my comment.  No it does not help, unless you want to handle framing errors.

Comment: Another issue with your implementation, is that the time between the START bit transition and the _centre_ of the first data bit is `delay_time * 3 / 2` - you are dangerously sampling close to the bit transitions rather then the bit centre.  Again - see my answer, not my comments - now with pictures!.

Comment: i understand what your are saying i will take care of these points during another test. Thanks

Comment: @Clifford Or you could, you know, design the hardware correctly. It will likely be both cheaper and better to fix the PCB layout.

Comment: @Lundin It is clearly off topic, but there are of course commercial considerations.  My point was simply not to dismiss the idea as "nonsense", even if this implementation or that attempt to achieve 115200 bps as an academic exercise is nonsense.

Answer (score 7):

The fundamental problem with your solution is that you are sampling the bits at the transition point rather then the bit centre.  On detection of the START transition, you delay one bit period only, so sample `r1` at the bit transition rather then the bit *centre* - this will almost certainly result in errors, especially at high speed where the edges may not be very fast.  The first delay should be 1.5 bit periods long. (`delay_time * 2 / 3`) as illustrated below:

[image]

A second problem is that you unnecessarily delay after the STOP bit, which will cause you to miss the next START transition because it may occur before you clear the interrupt flag. Your work is done as soon as you have `r8`.

Sampling `r0` and `r9` serves no purpose you discard them in any case, and the state `r0` is implicit in any event form the EXTI transition, and `r9` would only not be 1 if the sender was generating invalid frames.  Moreover if you are not sampling `r9` the delay before it also becomes unnecessary. These lines should be removed:

```
delay_us(delay_time);
r9 = GPIOA->IDR;
delay_us(delay_time);
```

That would at least give you two bit periods where your processor could do other work other then being stuck in the interrupt context, but delaying is an interrupt handler is not good practice - it blocks execution of normal code and all lower priority interrupts making the solution unsuited to real-time systems.  In this case if the soft-UART Rx is all the system has to do, you are likely to get better results by simply polling the GPIO rather then using interrupts - at least then other interrupts could run normally, and it is much simpler to implement.

Your "unrolled-loop" implementation also serves no real purpose with the delays in place - even at very high bit rates a loop overhead is likely to be insignificant over the duration of the frame, and if it were you could tweak the delays a little to compensate:

```
void EXTI0_IRQHandler(void)
{
    delay_us(delay_time * 2 / 3);
    for( int i = 7; i >= 0; i-- )
    {
        x |= GPIOA->IDR << i ;
        delay_us(delay_time);
    }

    EXTI->PR |= 0X00000001;
    buff1[z++] = x;
    x = 0 ;
    return ;
}
```

A more robust solution for a soft receiver that will play well with other processes in your system, should use the EXTI interrupt only to detect the start bit; the handler should disable the EXTI, and start a timer at the baud rate plus half a bit period.  The interrupt handler for the timer, samples the GPIO pin at the centre of the bit period, and on the first interrupt after the EXTI, changes the period to one bit period.  For each timer interrupt it samples and counts the bits until a whole data word has been shifted in, when it disables the timer and re-enables the EXTI for the next start bit.

I have successfully used this technique on STM32 running at 120MHz at 4800 and pushed it to 38400, but at 26 microseconds per bit it gets quite busy in the interrupt context, and your application presumably has other things to do?

The following is a slightly genericised version of my implementation.  It uses STM32 Standard Peripheral Library calls rather then direct register access or the later STM32Cube HAL, but you can easily port it one way or the other as you need.  The framing is N,8,1.

```
#define SOFT_RX__BAUD = 4800u ;
#define SOFT_RX_TIMER_RELOAD = 100u ;

void softRxInit( void )
{
    // Enable SYSCFG clock
    RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_SYSCFG, ENABLE);

    // Connect the EXTI Line to GPIO Pin
    SYSCFG_EXTILineConfig( EXTI_PortSourceGPIOB, EXTI_PinSource0 );

    TIM_Cmd( TIM10, DISABLE);

    // NVIC initialisation
    NVIC_InitTypeDef NVIC_InitStructure = {0,0,0,DISABLE};
    NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannel = TIM1_UP_TIM10_IRQn;
    NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority = 12; 
    NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority = 0;
    NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = ENABLE;
    NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStructure);

    // Enable peripheral clock to timers
    RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_TIM10, ENABLE);

    TIM_ARRPreloadConfig( TIM10, DISABLE );

    // Generate soft Rx rate clock (4800 Baud)
    TIM_TimeBaseInitTypeDef init = {0};
    TIM_TimeBaseStructInit( &init ) ;
    init.TIM_Period = static_cast<uint32_t>( SOFT_RX_TIMER_RELOAD );
    init.TIM_Prescaler = static_cast<uint16_t>( (TIM10_ClockRate() / (SOFT_RX__BAUD * SOFT_RX_TIMER_RELOAD)) - 1 );
    init.TIM_ClockDivision = 0;
    init.TIM_CounterMode = TIM_CounterMode_Up;
    TIM_TimeBaseInit( TIM10, &init ) ;

    // Enable the EXTI Interrupt in the NVIC
    NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannel = EXTI9_5_IRQn;
    NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority = 12;  
    NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority = 0;
    NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = ENABLE;
    NVIC_Init( &NVIC_InitStructure );

    // Dummy call to handler to force initialisation 
    // of UART frame state machine
    softRxHandler() ;
}

// Soft UART Rx START-bit interrupt handler
void EXTI0_IRQHandler()
{
    // Shared interrupt, so verify that it is the correct one
    if( EXTI_GetFlagStatus( EXTI_Line0 ) == SET )
    {
        // Clear the EXTI line pending bit.
        // Same as EXTI_ClearITPendingBit( EXTI_Line11 )
        EXTI_ClearFlag( EXTI_Line0 ) ;

        // Call Soft UART Rx handler
        softRxHandler() ;
    }
}

void TIM1_UP_TIM10_IRQHandler( void )
{
    // Call Soft UART Rx handler
    softRxHandler() ;

    TIM_ClearITPendingBit( TIM10, TIM_IT_Update );
}

// Handler for software UART Rx
inline void softRxHandler()
{
    static const int START_BIT = -1 ;
    static const int STOP_BIT = 8 ;
    static const int HALF_BIT = SOFT_RX_TIMER_RELOAD / 2;
    static const int FULL_BIT = SOFT_RX_TIMER_RELOAD ;
    static int rx_bit_n = STOP_BIT ;
    static const uint8_t RXDATA_MSB = 0x80 ;
    static uint8_t rx_data = 0 ;
    static EXTI_InitTypeDef extiInit = { EXTI_Line0,
                                         EXTI_Mode_Interrupt,
                                         EXTI_Trigger_Falling,
                                         DISABLE } ;

    // Switch START-bit/DATA-bit
    switch( rx_bit_n )
    {
        case START_BIT :
        {
            // Stop waiting for START_BIT
            extiInit.EXTI_LineCmd = DISABLE;
            EXTI_Init( &extiInit );

            // Enable the Interrupt
            TIM_ClearITPendingBit( TIM10, TIM_IT_Update );
            TIM_ITConfig( TIM10, TIM_IT_Update, ENABLE );

            // Enable the timer (TIM10)
            // Set time to hit centre of data LSB
            TIM_SetAutoreload( TIM10, FULL_BIT + HALF_BIT ) ;
            TIM_Cmd( TIM10, ENABLE );

            // Next = LSB data
            rx_data = 0 ;
            rx_bit_n++ ;
        }
        break ;

        // STOP_BIT is only set on first-time initialisation as a state, othewise it is
        // transient within this scase.
        // Use fall through and conditional test to allow
        // case to handle both initialisation and UART-frame (N,8,1) restart.
        case STOP_BIT :
        default :   // Data bits
        {
            TIM_ClearITPendingBit( TIM10, TIM_IT_Update );

            if( rx_bit_n < STOP_BIT )
            {
                if( rx_bit_n == 0 )
                {
                    // On LSB reset time to hit centre of successive bits
                    TIM_SetAutoreload( TIM10, FULL_BIT ) ;
                }

                // Shift last bit toward LSB (emulate UART shift register)
                rx_data >>= 1 ;

                // Read Rx bit from GPIO
                if( GPIO_ReadInputDataBit( GPIOB, GPIO_Pin_0 ) != 0 )
                {
                    rx_data |= RXDATA_MSB ;
                }

                // Next bit
                rx_bit_n++ ;
            }

            // If initial state or last DATA bit sampled...
            if( rx_bit_n == STOP_BIT )
            {
                // Stop DATA-bit sample timer
                TIM_Cmd( TIM10, DISABLE );

                // Wait for new START-bit
                rx_bit_n = START_BIT ;
                extiInit.EXTI_LineCmd = ENABLE;
                EXTI_Init( &extiInit );

                // Place character in Rx buffer
                serialReceive( rx_data ) ;
            }
        }
        break ;
    }
}
```

The code works in the same way as a real UART as illustrated in the timing diagrem above with the exception that in my implementation the STOP bit is not actually sampled - it is unnecessary; it only serves to ensure that the subsequent START bit is a 1 -> 0 transition and can generally be ignored.  A real UART would probably generate a framing error if it were not 1, but if you were not going to handle such errors in any event, there is no purpose in checking.

Comment: your code might not help me with 115200 baud rate. Because in many cases you had jump instructions in your code when written in assembly and i only have 8 us while working with 115200 buad rate. many sensors are pre-programmed at 115200 baud rate. But i like your logic and will try to implement it with some modifications

Comment: @Vaibhav : A soft UART at 115200 is ambitious in any event (8.7 microseconds per bit).  Your solution just means your processor will be able to do nothing with the data it receives if it is streaming, because it is always in the interrupt handler.

Comment: @Vaibhav : In a previous comment you suggested that this was an academic exercise.  As such, achieving 115200 will add nothing to your understanding of UART.  It seems that your primary issue is simply one of incorrect timing - the delay after the start bit transition being too short. In many cases, the CPU load imposed by a high-speed soft UART will compromise the actual function of your application.

Comment: being as academic exercise does not means that i will stop it if i was able to achieve a level. Exercise ends when i am able to achieve every level. Thanks for your concern.

Comment: @Vaibhav : You missed my point - going ever faster does not enhance your "_better understanding of UART_" which is your stated aim in the comment.  Moreover to what extent is 115200 "_every level_" - the STM32 h/w UART can achieve rates in the mega-bits-per-second range. Besides your question does not state a desired bit rate, and only 9600 is mentioned by you in comments.  That this solution may not achieve 115200 is an unfair criticism.  It allows other processes to run concurrently whilst yours will choke the processor.

Comment: I have previously implemented bit-banged UART reception for the purpose of automatically calculating received baud rates.  One thing you can do is enter your routine on a falling edge (which you assume is the start bit), then keep a timer running and record every time you see an edge after that.  Eventually, the signal goes back high (idle) and your "character" is done.  Then, you analyze the edges you saw and try to figure out what the bit time could be.  Usually, there's only one or two periods that work.  Finally, use start, stop & parity to figure out the likely bit rate.

Comment: @Vaibhav :  I have updated the answer to give an explanation of the issues with your solution other than simple interrupt handler abuse, and to propose a fix using your method.   My original answer then just remains a better practical solution if the application is to do any real work.

Comment: @DaveM.  I am not sure how baud rate detection is relevant to the question or why you have addressed your comment to my answer.

Comment: @clifford it is a reason to do bit-banging UART reception, similar to what the original poster was trying to do.  My method focuses on _edges_ of the serial signal, rather than trying to find the middle of the bit time (as you correctly point out, that is probably why the original code didn't work right).  The upside of "edge" focus is that you can recover the baud rate.  The downside is, you can't count on seeing an edge between every two bits, since successive bits might have the same value.

Comment: @DaveM. In that case you should apply the comment to the question, not my answer.  Or post an answer.

Comment: @Vaibhav It should be noted that the 38400 baud I suggested was achieved was on a real-time system with other work to do.  If your application is doing little else, (and in your implementation it has no choice), then 115200 would easily be achievable. You are sweating the small stuff worrying about a few single instructions.

Comment: @Clifford 1. to receive data on usart in any case controller is servicing usart receiver at that moment.  Holding the current process. 2. i my case i also doing that so that i didn't miss any bit, because any bit loss result is corrupt data. 3. I am satisfied with your logic will try that out once get a chance for it.

Comment: Once Just think about how normal UART transmitter receiver works.

Comment: I have no idea what your last comment means.  The one before that for point 1 for interrupt driven Rx, you get one interrupt per character, while the hardware is receiving the character you are free to do other work.  In your case you are in the interrupt context for 100% of the character receive time, by not needlessly waiting for the stop but, that can be improved to 80% while the per-character interrupt handling of a real UART is easily a tiny fraction of 1% - so don't tell me it makes no difference!  Using DMA the software overhead decreases further.

Comment: Further even if you poll the UART, you have up to two frame periods to read the data before an overrun occurs, so plenty of time to do something else.  In my soft RX set the interrupt priority higher than any other if there are other interrupts and you need high speed. The maximum speed can probably be improved greatly by replacing the standard peripheral library calls with direct register access - more so that worrying about the number of implicit jump instructions.

Comment: I think your question was about why your implementation did not work.  I think I have answered that, the alternative (more practical) solution you can take or leave. But if my indication of your erroneous timing was correct you might consider accepting this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see in your code where you take account of the *start bit* that is normally part of a serial transmission. You seem to be only looking for 8 data bits and a stop bit.

With the convention of "start bit is the inverse of stop bit" there will be an additional edge your code detects between characters, thus apparently shifting the bit stream you detect by one bit.

Comment: the logic i had written is working fine for single character. Rest as interrupt is falling edge triggered so during start condition the interrupt get automatically called. Then r0 is taking care of start condition an r9 is taking care of stop condition.

Comment: I would assume you re-enable the interrupt before the falling edge of the stop bit. That gives you an additional trigger and a shift by one bit. Check the "garbage" you get after the first character - If it's shifted by one bit, that's the problem.

Comment: what i am thinking that i was late for catching falling edge for next character. Stop bit is generated when line is pulled high as per the general usart timing diagram

Comment: @Vaibhav unnecessarily sampling the stop-bit an delaying is probably the reason you are only getting one character - you are in the interrupt context when the next start bit arrives. The stop bit can be ignored; it is only there to ensure the start bit is a transition.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that character 't' is received when string "test" is sent. 
Introduce sufficient inter character delay in the string. 
Hopefully it works. 
You can use docklite for sending string with inter character delay.